# Add number to alt of each image

Tags: jquery

I have one main image and four small ones. They all have alt="image".

```
<img src="image1.png" alt="image">
<div class="other-images">
 <img src="image2.png" alt="image">
 <img src="image3.png" alt="image">
 <img src="image4.png" alt="image">
 <img src="image5.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

What I would like to do is add number to each alt of small image starting with number 2 like so:

```
<div class="other-images">
 <img src="image2.png" alt="image-2">
 <img src="image3.png" alt="image-3">
 <img src="image4.png" alt="image-4">
 <img src="image5.png" alt="image-5">
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: If any of the provided solution worked please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple enough solution:

```
var i = 2;
$('.other-images').find('img').each(function (){
    $(this).attr('alt', 'image-' + (i++));
})
```

This uses `jQuery.each()` to loop over every element and add the appropriate alt attribute.

Comment: i knew i should use each()..just didnt know how to put it together. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the images and add the alt to each while incrementing the number:

```
var i = 2;
$('img').each(() => {
    $(this).attr('alt', 'image-' + (i++));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this ...........

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.other-images img').each(function(e) {
        var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
        $(this).attr('alt', alt+'-'+(e+2));
    });
</script>
```